# How to expand the side level menu click on the main page using ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to expand the side level drop down based on the categories. I have two pages one is menu.html and another is playlist.html. In playlist.html i have some categories based on which the side menu list should be expand. Both menu.html and playlist.html have the same categories using ionic and angular 1.x.

Please help me if possible or suggest me the link / answer to my question before down voting.

Thank U